# Arbitrary Precision for decimals in C# help?

Tags: c#, math, pi, arbitrary-precision

Here is my current code for computing Pi using the chudnovsky method in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using java.math;

namespace pi.chudnovsky
{
    public class Program
    {
        static Double Factorial(Double fact)
        {
            //begin factorial function
            if (fact <= 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return fact * Factorial(fact - 1); //loops multiplication until the factorial is reached
        }
        static Double doSummation(Double maxPower)
        {
            //begin chudnovsky summation function
            Double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= maxPower; i++) //starts at i=0
            {
                sum += ((Math.Pow(-1, i)) * Factorial(6 * i) * (13591409 + 5451401 * i)) / (Factorial(3 * i) * Factorial(i) * Factorial(i) * Factorial(i) * Math.Pow(640320, (3 * i + 1.5))); //chudnovsky algorithm
            }
            return sum;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter how many terms to compute Chudnovsky summation: ");
            //begin stopwatch
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            //parse user input
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //perform calculation
            Double inv = 1 / (12 * doSummation(num));
            //stop stopwatch
            stopwatch.Stop();
            //display info
            Console.WriteLine(inv);
            Console.WriteLine("3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510");
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            //write to pi.txt
            TextWriter pi = new StreamWriter("pi.txt");
            pi.WriteLine(inv);
            pi.Close();
            //write to stats.txt
            TextWriter stats = new StreamWriter("stats.txt");
            stats.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            stats.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I've included the J# library, and included java.math. Now when I replace all the "double"s with "BigDecimal"s, I get these compile errors:

http://f.cl.ly/items/1r2X26470d0d0n260p0p/Image%202011-11-14%20at%206.16.19%20PM.png

I know that this isn't the problem with me using Int for the loops, as it worked perfectly with Doubles. My question is, how do you resolve these errors relating to int and BigDecimal, or can you recommend another arbitrary precision library?

I've tried using XMPIR, have gotten everything to compile, but I get:

http://f.cl.ly/items/1l3C371j2u3z3n2g3a0j/Image%202011-11-14%20at%206.20.24%20PM.png

So I can I use p/invoke to include xmpir so I can use whatever the bigdecimal class is?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: why would you use a recursive factorial? wouldn't a lookup be better?

Comment: That class does not have the operators overloaded. You have you call `subtract`, `add`, `divide` methods, respectively.

Comment: btw in future I would recommend copying the actual compiler output into your question, rather than linking to an image. You can select+copy it from the `View | Output` window, changing the `Show ouput from` dropdown to `Build` if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not convert your int's to BigDecimal's before comparing them?

I assume you understand the problem here is that there is no operator overload for the greater, less than, etc. signs on the BigDecimal class that accepts an int.

Comment: I'm obviously only addressing your very first error on line 13.  But it looks like this is basically the same problem you're having everywhere.

Comment: Actually, I still need a bit of help. I really don't know how to use System.Convert, and the documentation isn't overly great. Can you show me an example on how to correct line 13?

Comment: System.Convert won't help you because it works with native .net types, of which BigInt is not one.  You can try casting like this '(BigInt)myVariable', but if that were possible you probably would have gotten a message saying something like there's no implicit cast but that there's an explicit one if you want to use it.  In order to compare BigInt to other types the BigInt class has to supply it's on operator overloads which it looks like there are none.  I think vcsjones answered your question above though, that BigInt has subtract, add, and divide methods that you can call.

Comment: So if nothing else, you should be able to just do something like "var myBigInt = new BigInt(); myBigInt.Add(myVariable);" to get your double into a BigInt.